# Proof of density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the proof of density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ presented in a video lecture by Winston Ou and inspired by Baby Rudin.

The claim is that given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x < y$, there exists $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x < q < y$. I am going to replicate his proof, stopping where I get stuck. We are taking the Archimedean property for granted.

> If $x < y$, $y - x > 0$, so by the Archimedean property, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n(y-x) > 1$.

I'm ok so far, but I do wonder why I'm not allowed at this point to say $ny - nx > 1$, so there exists $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $nx < z < ny$, so $x < \frac{z}{n} < y$, and then the proof is complete.  Is there something wrong with finishing the proof there?

> Continuing with the proof. Applying the Archimedean property twice more, we find $m_1, m_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $m_1 \cdot 1 > nx$ and $m_2 \cdot 1 > - nx$, so $-m_2 < nx$. So $-m_2 < nx < m_1$. Let $S = \{z \in \mathbb{Z} \mid nx < z \leq m_1\}$.

I am confused twice at this point. First, why define the set this way? That is, why do I require $z$ to be *strictly* greater than $nx$? Why would it not suffice to say that $nx \leq z \leq m_1$? I'm not seeing the full link. Second, we want to eventually find a least element. The second is finite since $nx$ and $m_1$ are finite -- that makes enough sense intuitively -- but how do I know $S$ is nonempty? What if $nx = 4.1$ and $m_1 = 5$? Then, there are no integers $z$ with this property and I certainly cannot find a least element. On the flip side, if I required $nx \leq z \leq m_1$, I can take $z = 5$.

> Proceeding, assuming that I have found such a least element $m$ which is the smallest element of $S$ satisfying $nx < m \leq n_1$, I know that $m-1 < m$ surely does not satisfy this property. Certainly $m - 1 < m \leq n_1$, so we must have $m-1 \leq nx$. So $m \leq nx + 1$. So we have $nx < m \leq nx + 1 < ny$ (by choice of $n$, so $nx < m < ny$, so $x < \frac{m}{n} < y$, and the proof is complete.

I'd appreciate any help. I'm still trying to put the pieces together in my head so that this proof makes sense.

Comment: When proving basic properties, you have to be careful about what you assume.  I agree that if $r,s$ are real numbers such that $r-s > 1$, then there's some integer $z$ such that $s < z < r$, but this is not definitionally true, so we'd need to prove it.  What proof would you like to use?

Comment: This is a good point. I was thinking it followed from the well ordering principle, but I can't articulate a formal argument for that.

Comment: as a lemma, show the following: $$\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}:[\mathbb{Z}\cap(a,b)=\emptyset\Longrightarrow b-a\leq 1]$$ so by the contrapositive, you have the statement $$\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}:[b-a>1\Longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\cap(a,b)\neq\emptyset]$$

Comment: @CSquared Does the proof you have in mind involve the floor function? That's the only thing I can think to use. If $\mathbb{Z} \cap (a,b) = \emptyset$, the integer part of $a,b$ has to be the same, right?

Comment: no. here is an outline: wlog suppose $b>a$ and $\mathbb{Z}\cap(a,b)=\emptyset$. Observe that $L\cup U=\mathbb{Z}$ forms a disjoint union of $\mathbb{Z}$ where $$L=\{z\in\mathbb{Z}:z\leq a\},U=\{z\in\mathbb{Z}:z\geq b\}$$ Since $L$ is a non-empty, bounded above subset of integers, then it has a maximal element, say $\ell$. Then $\ell\in L$ and $\ell+1\in U$. you should be able to finish from here.

Comment: Not sure if the OP still wants to see an answer giving a proof that $\quad$  IF $ny - nx > 1$ THEN there exist a $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $nx < z < ny$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm ok so far, but I do wonder why I'm not allowed at this point to say $ny - nx > 1$, so there exists $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $nx < z < ny$, so $x < \frac{z}{n} < y$, and then the proof is complete.  Is there something wrong with finishing the proof there?

I'm just going to copy my comment:

> When proving basic properties, you have to be careful about what you assume. I agree that if $r,s$ are real numbers such that $r−s>1,$ then there's some integer $z$ such that $s<z<r,$ but this is not definitionally true, so we'd need to prove it. What proof would you like to use?

I've not thought through the proof, but I think it would be similar to some of the steps in the proof you're currently asking about.

---

> First, why define the set this way? That is, why do I require $z$ to be *strictly* greater than $nx$? Why would it not suffice to say that $nx \leq z \leq m_1$?

If we did so, then later in the proof we'd be able to prove only $x \leq \frac{m}{n} < y$, which doesn't suffice to prove density.  For that, we need strict inequality between each of $x,y$ and the rational number $\frac{m}{n}$.

> but how do I know $S$ is nonempty? What if $nx = 4.1$ and $m_1 = 5$? Then, there are no integers $z$ with this property and I certainly cannot find a least element.

I think you're confused.  If $nx = 4.1$ and $m_1 = 5$, then $4.1 < 5 \leq 5$ means that $5 \in S$.  In fact, since the inequality on the right is non-strict, then we *always* have $m_1 \in S$, so it's not empty.

Comment: I was definitely confused and I appreciate the clarification. This helps. Would you mind saying just a bit more about how we know $S$ is nonempty, though? The only thing I can think to do is to sort through cases. Otherwise, I worry that this is similar to wanting to assert there's an integer between $ny$ and $nx$: we know it to be true, but I can't really "justify" it.

Comment: @BradG. There's really not much to mention here.  By that point, you've already shown by the Archimedean property that there exists some [positive] $m_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $nx < m_1$.  Since $m_1 \leq m_1$ is true by the reflexive property, we have $nx < m_1 \leq m_1$, showing that $m_1 \in S$.  Since $m_1 \in S$, $S$ must be nonempty.